# Using regular expression to search and replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write a query in MySQL to update a field by adding a new text string to the start of its existing text, creating a new line, and then adding the original text.

I have looked into regexp, but am unsure as to whether I am using it properly, as my query doesn't seem to work with the match.

The query I am using is as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'REGEXP ^', ''new_text' REGEXP \n field');
```

The ^ represents the beginning of the string(start of the text) that I wish to update in the field.

The replacing text consists of the new_text string, the new line (\n) and the original field.

I am relatively new to MySQL, so any insight into the structure of this query and whether it is possible to implement would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

If you have a table of people

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Bob   |
|  2 | Frank |
+----+-------+
```

Doing

```
UPDATE people SET name = CONCAT('Mr. ', name) WHERE id = 1;
```

Will give you

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Mr. Bob |
|  2 | Frank   |
+----+---------+
```